# Connection to PostgreSQL DB failure

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am currently working on a **3.5 .NET C# Project**. it uses an external program that takes an argument when I build and run it. The external program goes to index a structured or an unstructured source of data.

The C# project is a **simple .dll** that override some of the external program methods. At the initialization part, I do request a connection to my **postgreSQL DB** in order to get back a unique ID.

*WARNING : Indexer and my DB have no link, Indexer can index folder with .xls files, or mysql DB. My PostgreSQL is here just to bring a unique ID and store some important informations*

My problem is when I launch as an external program the **DBConnector which is a 32 bit** indexer, everything goes well.

Whereas when I launch the **AlfrescoConnector which is a 64 bit indexer**, I can't open my postgreSQL database.

*I put the x86 & x64 type of connector but I don't know if the problem comes from there.*

I'm working on **Visual 2012**, my debug is set to produce a x86 compatible program (changing it to "any CPU" or "x64" doesn't solve the problem)

The db object I use is DbClient which is a specific method that you won't find on the internet because it comes from the external program reference, but it works as a classic DbConnector.

My DbClient object looks like this :

- dbClient = {Sinequa.Common.DbClient}

  - _CurrentTransaction = null
  - ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5444;User Id=USERSAMPLE;Database=DBSAMPLE;Password=PWDSAMPLE;"
  - DbCn = null
  - DbCnSubSelect = null
  - DbFactory = null
  - DbIsolationLevel = Unspecified
  - DefaultCommandBehavior = SequentialAccess
  - Engine = Postgres
  - Error = 0
  - ErrorText = null
  - LastRowAffected = 0
  - LOBFetchSize = 0
  - Provider = "Npgsql"
  - RefreshCount = 0
  - RefreshCurrent = 0
  - Schema = null

The error comes when I do `myDbClient.Open()` with the Alfresco one

Any suggestions ? Need more details ? I'm ready to solve this painful error with you my fellows !

Comment: Inspecting the log files generated by the connector named Alfresco, I succeed into discriminating the source of the problem :

"DbClient.Open error : Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."

The one I currently use is Npgsql.

Is making reference to Npgsql will fill the lack of information included directly into the connector ?

I'll experiment by my side, but feel free to add some valuable answers to this topic.

Answer (score 2):

The Alfresco x64 bit connector use the x64 bit of the .NET configuration file. The configuration files located at:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.conf
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.conf
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.conf
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.conf
```

Remember that the problem is the missing provider. So to solve this problem you have to insert the lacking provider between the DbProviderFactories tag like this:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Odbc" type="System.Data.Odbc.OdbcFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  <add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for OleDb" type="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OracleClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle" type="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=2.0.13.91, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"/>
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

With this insert the next time the DbClient will try to open the Database and get the asked provider, it will succeed.